# 'NSUnknownKeyException' occured, but I can't find wrong connection

Tags: ios, nsunknownkeyexception, xcode8

I upgrade my iphone's ios ver to 10.0 and xcode's ver to 8.0(beta).
Source code well done in xcode ver 7.3.1.
but, when i run code in xcode 8.0,

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[ setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key idTextField.'

show up.

there is no '!' mark in xib. how can i fix it?
[xib image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0cXGN.png)

```
@interface TutorialViewController () <UIScrollViewDelegate>
{
IBOutlet UIScrollView *tutorialScrollView;
IBOutlet UIPageControl *pageControl;

IBOutlet UIButton *showTermsButton;
IBOutlet UIButton *showPrivacyPolicyButton;
ContactsManager *contactsManager;


IBOutlet UITextField *idTextField;
IBOutlet UITextField *pwTextField;
}


-(IBAction)showTerms:(id)sender;
-(IBAction)showPrivacyPolicy:(id)sender;
-(IBAction)start:(id)sender;
-(IBAction)startWithFacebook:(id)sender;
-(IBAction)goToSignUpPage:(id)sender;

@end

@implementation TutorialViewController
```

Comment: Can you post some code of your View Controller?

Comment: HI, @Ike10. I edit my question. plz show them :)

Comment: @interface TutorialViewController .. does it subclass UIViewController ?

Comment: @Shubhank Sure. interface TutorialViewController : UIViewController.

Comment: can you upload the project on github ? or maybe mail so that one can look over it ?

Comment: It is a bug in xcode 8 beta. it works well now ! : )